# AngularJS Componet testing with ng-html2js

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ng-html2js

Can someone help me with that problem:

Angular project:

**gui_service/client/src/js/remoteGuiApp.js:**

```
angular.module('remoteGuiApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngResource'])
```

**gui_service/client/src/modules/login/login.js**

```
angular.module('remoteGuiApp')
.component('login', {
    controller: function () {
        this.login = '';
        this.password = '';
        this.showError = false;
    },
    templateUrl: '/src/modules/login/login.html'
});
```

Also I have '/src/modules/login/login.html' template for this component.

**gui_service/client/test/karma.conf**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    'use strict';
    config.set({

        basePath: '',

        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],

        files: [
            '../src/vendor/js/angular.min.js',
            '../src/vendor/js/angular-mocks.js',
            '../src/vendor/js/angular-route.min.js',
            '../src/vendor/js/angular-resource.min.js',
            '../src/vendor/js/angular-sanitize.min.js',
            '../src/vendor/js/angular-cookies.min.js',

            //Library Files
             '../src/vendor/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',
             '../src/vendor/js/moment.js',
             '../src/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js',
             '../src/vendor/js/ui-bootstrap.js',

            '../src/js/remoteGuiApp.js',
            '../src/js/Authentication.js',
            '../src/modules/login/login.js',

            //tests
             '*.js',
             //templates
             '../src/modules/**/*.html'
        ],

        // generate js files from html templates
        preprocessors: {
           '../src/modules/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
        },

        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            // strip this from the file path
            stripPrefix: 'client/'
        },

        reporters: ['mocha'],

        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        autoWatch: true,
        singleRun: false,

        // level of logging
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        concurrency: Infinity
    });
};
```

And finally my problem point:
**gui_service/client/test/LoginComponent-test.js:**

```
describe('Component: login', function () {
    beforeEach(module('remoteGuiApp'));

    // load the login template
    beforeEach(module('/src/modules/login/login.html'));

    let scope;
    let element;
    let controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        element = angular.element('<login></login>');

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

  it('Controller fields', function(done) {
      expect(true).true;
      done();
  });

});
```

As result of launching karma I have error like this: [angular link error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=%2Fsrc%2Fmodules%2Flogin%2Flogin.html&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.4%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3D%252Fsrc%252Fmodules%252Flogin%252Flogin.html%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2FC:%2FGitRepository%2Fremote%2Fgui_service%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fvendor%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3F9c923313eabc56d715a7c07bf855feb26a72f671:6:425%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2FabsoluteC:%2FGitRepository%2Fremote%2Fgui_service%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fvendor%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3F9c923313eabc56d715a7c07bf855feb26a72f671:26:270%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2FabsoluteC:%2FGitRepository%2Fremote%2Fgui_service%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fvendor%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3F9c923313eabc56d715a7c07bf855feb26a72f671:25:299)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2FabsoluteC:%2FGitRepository%2Fremote%2Fgui_service%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fvendor%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3F9c923313eabc56d715a7c07bf855feb26a72f671:26:44%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2FabsoluteC:%2FGitRepository%2Fremote%2Fgui_service%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fvendor%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3F9c923313eabc56d715a7c07bf855feb26a72f671:42:117%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2FabsoluteC:%2FGitRepository%2Fremote%2Fgui_service%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fvendor%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3F9c923313eabc56d715a7c07bf855feb26a72f671:7:495)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2FabsoluteC:%2FGitRepository%2Fremote%2Fgui_service%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fvendor%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3F9c923313eabc56d715a7c07bf855feb26a72f671:41:476)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.eb%20%5Bas%20injector%5D%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2FabsoluteC:%2FGitRepository%2Fremote%2Fgui_service%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fvendor%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3F9c923313eabc56d715a7c07bf855feb26a72f671:46:44)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Context.WorkFn%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2FabsoluteC:%2FGitRepository%2Fremote%2Fgui_service%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fvendor%2Fjs%2Fangular-mocks.js%3F861c27a0d62d5f7beed79cd1b40b44f0560b2eb5:3163:52)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20callFn%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:9876%2FabsoluteC:%2FGitRepository%2Fremote%2Fnode_modules%2Fmocha%2Fmocha.js%3F0491afff0b566ea45cd04c9164a355dba705689e:4447:21))

Maybe someone will tell the solution to this problem. Thank's for your help.

Comment: why are you passing a HTML file path in the `module(...)`?

Comment: because I'm using karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor

Comment: I don't have much idea about that but looking at your angular link error, it seems like that's the culprit here..

Comment: Yes, I'm understand it but my main question how configure it right.  I try do it by this official example https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing, but something wrong with it...

Comment: can you try removing the `/` before `src/modules/...` in `beforeEach(module(...))`?

Comment: Thank's for idea, but it not help, in additional this string must be the same as templateUrl property in login.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it.
The main problem was in paths. So if you need configure karma.conf.js for test  Angular directive/component with templateUrl's be careful with tags:

```
basePath: ''
preprocessors: ''
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            stripPrefix: ''
            prependPrefix: ''
        },
```

Read manual very carefuly https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor/blob/master/README.md#configuration so as not to step on the rake as I did)